# Не работает monitor коллекции. Ошибка Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: коллекции, postman, monitor

Создал простейшую коллекцию методов для работы с REST API.

Все методы POST. Авторизация Basic Auth. Тело запроса JSON.

Каждый метод по отдельности работает, коллекция тоже.

Однако при попытке подключить monitor к коллекции я получаю ошибку:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 212.45.14.125:443

При этом Postman даже не делает запроса по http - смотрел снифером. IP-адрес из ошибки вообще не имеет никакого отношения к используемым мной адресам, более того он не резолвится вообще, nslookup тоже ничего не видит. Адрес вроде бы COMCOR (Акадо) принадлежит.
Экспериметы с VPN и разными провайдерами ничего не дали.

Основной вопрос - зачем Postman стучится куда-то ещё, именно в мониторе? Ведь коллекция отрабатывает нормально.